# how to input in excel in java

Tags: java, excel

HOw do we input data in excel sheet using java code , the excel sheet format is shown in the photo below.

The Total days and Hrs are calculated automatically here in sheet as soon as i enter in the above columns, Please tell me how do start . Also these input are associated to the other sheet(sheet2) . so please tell me the way so that it also flexible and i can modify the data in the sheet2.

![[Excel sheet that needs to be automated][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMFFO.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use a third party library like [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) for reading Excel data in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the jexcelapi found on sourceforge: [JExcelApi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/)

Very easy to use to read & write excel files from java.

Answer (score 0):

You use Java Excel API. This is an excellent article that demonstrates [reading from and writing to Excel with Java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html).

Here is the Java Excel API [download](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).